# creating correlation matrix publication ready

Tags: r, flextable, cross-correlation

I am a relative newbie in R.
I want to create a correlation matrix ready for publication (in a word document).
I want the matrix to show the correlations and stars for significance.

Here is what I did so far:

```
library(flextable)
library(psych)

# Creating data frame
var1 <- c(2,3,1,5,4,5)
var2 <- c(23,25,21,31,67,43)
var3 <- c(2,5,98,4,3,54)

df <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3)

#running correlation with psych package
df.corr <- psych::corr.test(df, adjust = "none")


# create correlation table with flextable package.

inter_corr_r <- as.data.frame(df.corr$r) # changing to data frame.

ft.corr <-flextable(inter_corr_r) %>%
  colformat_double(
    digits = 2
  )

ft.corr
```

Here is the results:

[image]

Missing is the first column with the names of the variables and the significant stars. If easier and better, a solution using gtsummary can be suitable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the already formatted `stars` table returned as an element of the `corr.test` object and add the row names manually:

```
library(flextable)
library(psych)

# Creating data frame
var1 <- c(2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 5)
var2 <- c(23, 25, 21, 31, 67, 43)
var3 <- c(2, 5, 98, 4, 3, 54)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

df.corr <- psych::corr.test(df, adjust = "none")

inter_corr_r <- df.corr$stars
inter_corr_r <- cbind(var = rownames(inter_corr_r), inter_corr_r)
inter_corr_r <- as.data.frame(inter_corr_r)

ft.corr <- flextable(inter_corr_r) |> 
  set_header_labels(var = "")
ft.corr
```

[image]